# Move ActiveCell back to the cell whose value got changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that needs to run when a cell value gets changed.

This is what I have. This doesn't work because when I change the value of cell and then hit Enter or click on some other cell, the macro takes values from the cell that I have moved to and not from the cell whose value I changed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B3:V34")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
    On Error GoTo Finalize 'to re-enable the events
    MsgBox (Target.Address)
    'prints the cell address whose value I changed before I clicked on some other cell
    MsgBox (ActiveCell.Address)
    'prints the cell address of the new cell where I have moved to
    ActiveCell.Range(Target.Address).Activate
    'This is me trying to move the active cell to the cell whose value I changed
    'But this doesn't work. The activeCell moves to some random cell
    'I wanna run a macro here which takes activeCell address and value as input
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: (a) `ActiveCell.Range(Target.Address).Activate` is not moving you to a "random" cell.  Knowing the `Target.Address` and the `ActiveCell.Address`, it is a simple exercise to calculate what it is going to "Activate".  (b) I think you want `Target.Activate`, or (if you want to be verbose) `Range(Target.Address).Activate` (c) You shouldn't need to "re-activate" `Target` - you can just use `Target.Value` to get the value of the cell that was changed.

Comment: @YowE3K `Target.Activate` moved the `ActiveCell` back to the cell whose value I had changed. Thank you. Can you tell me how `Target.Address` is different from `ActiveCell.Address` and how do you calculate which cell is going to activate? Thank you so much

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` event is passed a parameter (i.e. `Target`) which is the cell that was changed.  So `Target.Address` is the address of the changed cell.  `ActiveCell` is the currently active cell which, based on your description of what you are doing, is the cell you have clicked on.

Comment: If (for instance) `Target.Address` was `$D$5` and `ActiveCell.Address` was `$J$10` then your old code would have activated `$M$14`, i.e. the cell that was 3 columns to the right and 4 rows below cell `$J$10`.  The "3 columns to the right and 4 rows below" is determined because that is the position of `$D$5` from the origin of a worksheet (i.e. from cell `$A$1`), and you have told it to pretend that the origin is instead `$J$10`.